# bash output with extra newline within the string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I use the following command to output PID and FD related to CLOSE-WAIT sockets.

```
sudo ss -p | grep CLOSE-WAIT | awk '{ print $7 }' | sed 's/,pid=/ /' | sed 's/,fd=/ /' | sed 's/))//' | awk '{ print $2, $3 }'
```

It outputs correctly where a PID FD pair takes one line like below.

```
22487 27
22652 21
21846 33
21780 26
22476 14
21571 10
22740 17
21901 26
```

But if I use the for loop it outputs differently.

```
#!/bin/bash


for PidFd in `sudo ss -p | grep CLOSE-WAIT | awk '{ print $7 }' | sed 's/,pid=/ /' | sed 's/,fd=/ /' | sed 's/))//' | awk '{ print $2, $3 }'`
do
    echo "$PidFd"
done
```

It adds extra newline between the two.

```
22487
27
22652
21
21846
33
21780
26
22476
14
21571
10
22740
17
21901
26
```

I would like to fix that to have the same output.

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Also, `grep | awk` is silly. `awk` can filter. (It can _also_ do everything `sed` can too).

Comment: ...for that matter, would you consider accepting an answer that did all this in native bash, and didn't use `sed` or `awk` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an extra newline because `for` doesn't just split on newlines -- it also splits on spaces, so instead of getting a pid/fd pair assigned to `PidFd`, it *first* has a PID assigned, and *then* has a FD. As extensively documented at [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), the best-practice approach is to use a `while read` loop instead.

Moreover, one doesn't need to use `awk`, `grep`, or `sed` at all for what you're trying to accomplish here (although `grep` can help performance on systems with a large number of sockets, at the expense of making it worse on systems with only a small number of sockets):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "ERROR: Your shell must be bash, not sh" >&2; exit 1;; esac

pid_re='pid=([[:digit:]]+)($|[^[:digit:]])'
fd_re='fd=([[:digit:]]+)($|[^[:digit:]])'
while IFS= read -r line; do pid=; fd=
  [[ $line =~ $pid_re ]] && pid=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  [[ $line =~ $fd_re ]] && fd=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  [[ $pid && $fd ]] && echo "$pid $fd"
done < <(sudo ss -p | grep CLOSE-WAIT)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Charles commented, awk can do the whole pipeline

```sh
sudo ss -p | awk '
    /CLOSE-WAIT/ {
        field = $7
        sub(/,pid=/, " ", field)
        sub(/,fd=/, " ", field)
        sub(/))/, "", field)
        split(field, a)
        print a[2], a[3]
    }
'
```

The bash [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) command can read *lines* into an array:

```sh
mapfile -t lines < <(
    sudo ss -p | awk '
        /CLOSE-WAIT/ {
            field = $7
            sub(/,pid=/, " ", field)
            sub(/,fd=/, " ", field)
            sub(/))/, "", field)
            split(field, a)
            print a[2], a[3]
        }
    '
)
```

Now, you can do

```sh
for PidFd in "${lines[@]}"; do
    echo "$PidFd"
done
```